# Meaning of も and は in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-も

I think it is safe to assume the speaker is also not the most organised person in this sentence:

> 「あなた、もう少し計画的に行動した方がいいよ。わたし**も**他人のこと**は**言えないけどさ」
>   You should behave a little more systematically. I ? can't say this of other people but...

The whole of the second sentence is confusing me a little. Is the highlighted は an emphatic replacement of を?

What is the function of も here? It doesn't seem to work as either 'also' or 'even' to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I parse the sentence you've got:

> あなた、もう少し計画的に行動した方がいいよ。

For the first half, I think your translation is decent.

But to do it slightly more literally:
= It would be better if your actions were more planned.

したほうがいい → "It would better if" / there are other constructions that express "should" more directly.

計画的 → you've translated this as systematically, but I think in context it makes sense to more directly express "plans"

> わたしも他人のことは言えないけどさ」

For the second sentence, I think the basic sentiment is all ぼかし表現 (things to soften the previous sentence).

Going through it piece by piece,

- 私も - I think here the も is because the previous sentence is criticism of the other person, so here the speaker is indicating that they also have will criticize their own self.
- 他人のこと - I don't think this is "other people" but rather "other people's stuff" / "other people's matters" / "other people's junk"
- は言えない - I think the reason why there's a は here is that the preceding part of the sentence is the sort of thing that the subject feels is a character flaw they should improve on. While literally "I can't really talk", I think the sense is "I shouldn't really talk" or "it's not my place to talk about "
- けどさ - I think this けどさ is not a real attempt at conjunction, it's an attempt to soften the sentence

So I put the second half together as "But I am not really someone to talk about  other people's issues."  (the wording might be too American -- the point being "I've got issues too -- like talking about other people -- so I'm going to shut up now").

Or at least that's my sense. If I'm wrong I hope to learn how to do better by getting comments or corrections.

## tl;dr

I think the も is to say sentence 1 criticizes あなた and sentence 2 is criticizing 自分

I think the は marks off what the problem is with the speaker (talking about other people's issues) rather than being something where it would make much sense to view it as a substitute for を or が.

But I take the entire point of the second sentence to be: I just said something sharply critical about you, so now I'm going to try to soften that with a "we all have problems and here's one of mine."

Answer (score 0):

What about this:
あなた、もう少し計画的に行動した方がいいよ。わたしもけどさ。
You should behave a little more systematically. And so should I though.

He is criticizing someone for being sloppy, when he himself is sloppy.
That is why he says 他人のことは言えない.
He can't really say this about other people when he himself is sloppy.

So も here means "also".

Comment: わたしもけどさ is incorrect. We say わたしも**だ**けどさ.

Answer (score 0):

> わたし**も**他人のことは言えないけど *さ*

To me it feels like:

"I'm no one to point other people's shortcomings **either**, *you know*? but..."